# Are there any libraries that provide an administrative CLI for a C/C++ daemon?

Tags: c, admin, command-line-interface, daemon

I'm looking for some kind of embedded shell we can stick in a C/C++ daemon. The idea is that we can telnet to a port that's being listened on, and change configuration/view status/etc.

Something like the CLI that Quagga/Zebra has (which is modeled on IOS) or similar. Ideally has readline-like support for ease of use, and easily extensible for us to add new features to it.

I've thought about using something like embedded Python or Lua to provide a shell in that language, but I've never actually seen anyone else do this.

Anyone else mind chiming in with how they've accomplished this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libcli will do what you want. It also features authentication, works over the command line, telnet and you can easily build clients to work however you want it too. Very cisco like with automatic completion, sub commands etc. You can find it here :
https://github.com/dparrish/libcli

Here's a tiny example implementing the command "hello" and letting you telnet to it on port 12345:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <libcli.h>

int call_hello(struct cli_def *cli, char *name, char **argv, int argc) {
    cli_print(cli, "hello world");
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    struct cli_def *cli;
    int sockfd;
    int acceptfd;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr, raddr;
    unsigned int on = 1;
    unsigned int rlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    cli = cli_init();
    cli_register_command(cli, NULL, "hello", call_hello,
                         PRIVILEGE_UNPRIVILEGED, MODE_ANY, "runs hello world");

    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
         perror("socket");
         exit(-1);
    }
    saddr.sin_port = htons(12345);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&raddr, 0, sizeof(raddr));
    raddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) != 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) == -1) {
         perror("bind");
         exit(-1);
    }
    if(listen(sockfd, 12) != 0) {
         perror("listen");
         exit(-1);
    }
    while((acceptfd=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&raddr, &rlen)) > 0) {    
         while(cli_loop(cli, acceptfd) == 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what i saw before! Somehow searching for a "library" for a "CLI" didn't inspire me to try "libcli". Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding in a local HTTP server so you can do your configuration via a simple web client?  Web pages are pretty flexible and easy to use ;)  e.g. see Poco's HTTPServer class (http://pocoproject.org/docs/)

Comment: That was probably my fallback option, but all of us here really preferred a CLI of some kind. I'll have a deeper look at Poco. Thanks. :)

Comment: Add an HTML text field where you can enter some Lua text, have the Lua execute and the result shown on a web page. Not super interactive, but some admin things will be far easier with buttons and checkboxes than CLI interaction.

Comment: Regarding an embedded http server this might also be of interest: http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/ @whamma

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is implement your own CMD.EXE(or a terminal emulator) like utility, except built into your GUI. How I have accomplished something like this before? I have read the manuals for VT100 terminal and how to emulate that. Then went about implementing a custom-component in .NET for the same

Comment: I'm not really looking for fancy terminal emulation or anything, something like readline can handle that. I'm pretty sure I saw *somewhere* a precanned library that gave a nice CLI for managing configuration, status and maintenance tasks that we could run in a child thread or similar.